# Disable safecrlf for particular file

Tags: git, newline, core.autocrlf

I'm using Windows. I have the following settings in my ~/.gitconfig:

```
[core]
    autocrlf = input
    safecrlf = true
```

I have three files for my example repository: `lf.txt` with LF line endings; `crlf.txt` with CRLF line endings and `auto.txt` with CRLF line endings. I want first two files to keep those line endings when checked out anywhere. For `auto.txt` I want git to convert CRLF to LF on commit and checkout as LF.

To add `crlf.txt` with CRLF line endings, I have to write following line to `.gitattributes`

```
crlf.txt eol=crlf
```

But I can't add `auto.txt` while keeping global `safecrlf = true` setting (and I want to keep that setting, as it's useful and prevents me from accidentally checking in CRLF file).

I tried to add following line to `.gitattributes` expecting it to work:

```
auto.txt safecrlf=false
```

or

```
auto.txt core.safecrlf=false
```

but Git ignores it.

Comment: `core.safecrlf` is a global flag and cannot be set or cleared per file. When set, it just sets flags in an internal variable, `global_conv_flags_eol`, that affects the behavior of crlf conversions. The flags have three possible states: say nothing, warn, or error. I'm not sure you can achieve your goal.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I can just turn it off globally, add file and turn it on back. Not as handy but I can live with it I guess.